# Random array in server and client in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to randomize an array of objects in server that matches in the client. I've tried to solve it using a state, useMemo hook... and the thing is that client and server never match.

For example, this code rendered in server is different from the one after hydration in client:

```
const myArray = [{
    id: 1,
}, {
    id: 2,
}, {
    id: 3,
}];

// ........

export default function Component(myArray) {
    const [randomized] = React.useState(suffleArray(myArray));


    React.useEffect(() => {
        trackValues(randomized);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {
                randomized.map(({ id }) => id)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The important thing here is that I want a different order in each page load, but the HTML returned must be the same in both server and client.

Comment: How often should the numbers be shuffled?

Comment: Every time the component is rendered

Comment: The only way to achieve that is to generate your random array either on the client or server and push the result to the other party using a network request.

Comment: You could also use a seeded random number generator and use the same seed on the client and server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve the same order of randomization in two different machines at the same time.

if you want to achieve this you have to create your own randomization function which runs based on a key(which should be available in both servers)

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```js
// Server-side code
const seed = 'your seed value'; // Set a fixed seed value
const randomArray = [...yourArray]; // Create a copy of your array

// Function to shuffle the array using the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
}

// Seed the random number generator
Math.seed = seed;

// Shuffle the array using the seeded random number generator
shuffleArray(randomArray);

// Send the randomized array to the client-side as part of the response
res.send({ randomArray });
```

```js
//Client Side

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Assume you received the randomized array from the server as `randomArray`

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [shuffledArray, setShuffledArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShuffledArray(randomArray);
  }, []);

  // Render the component with the shuffledArray
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Use the shuffledArray in your UI */}
      {shuffledArray.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Seed the random number generator: Start by seeding the random number generator on both the server and client using the same value. This will ensure that they generate the same sequence of random numbers. For example, you can use a fixed seed value like Math.seed = 'your seed value';.

Generate a random order on the server: On the server side, randomize the array of objects using the seeded random number generator. You can use a shuffling algorithm like the Fisher-Yates shuffle. Make sure to use the same seed value you set in step 1.

Send the randomized array to the client: Once you have the randomized array on the server, send it to the client-side as part of the response.

Use the randomized array on the client: On the client side, use the received randomized array to populate your UI or perform any required operations. Ensure that you're not re-randomizing the array on the client-side.

Comment: I'd like to use the same code in client / server. Probably it works (but Math.seed? is that okey?), but I was looking for something simple